# Task scheduling with priority and pass fail results

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, thread-priority

Currently, my code looks something like this.

```
public class myClass
{

    public myClass fullyReduce()
    {
        myClass old = this.ShallowCopy();
        myClass reduced = reduce();
        while(old!=reduced )
        {
            old = reduced ;
            reduced = old.reduce();
        }
        return reduced;
    }

    private myClass reduce()
    {
        //Takes 24 Milliseconds on average
        myClass FactorReduced = FactorReduction();
        if(FactorReduced != this)
            return FactorReduced();

        //Takes 6 Millisecounds
        myClass PrimeReduced = PrimeReduction();
        if(PrimeReduced != this)
            return PrimeReduced();

        //Takes 14 Millisecounds
        myClass FractionReduced = FractionReduction();
        if(FractionReduced != this)
            return FractionReduced();

        //And so fourth until
        return this;
    }
}
```

This works as it is.

### Parallel

However each of the reduction (FactorReduction, PrimeReduction, FractionReduction) are not running in parallel and are running one after the other. Each of these functions are thread safe and can run parallel and this is not taking advantage of that. In what way can I have each of these all run at the same time, and take the result of the **first one that returns with a pass**, since sometimes the reduction will fail to reduce it any further.

### Priority

Additionally the order in which the tasks run in my example is dependent on what arbitrary order I write them. I would rather be able to set a priority for each Task *(I plan to get these priorty numbers from average computation time and average success)*

A helpful answer could show a dummy implementation based on the sample code which accomplishes what the code previously did with the additional multi-threading I require.

Thanks in advance, I've tried to be as clear as I can, and if you don't understand what I mean, just comment on this question and I'll fix up any mistakes/vagueness.